# Why does amsmath use fraktur for real and imaginary parts?

Tags: tex-history

> Edit: When writing this I was under the impression that this was amsmath's choice. It has now been bought to my attention that it is Knuth's.

When was it decided that amsmath would have the real part notation as an uppercase fraktur variation R rather than a Re? (same question for the imaginary parts).

What was the motive for this?

IMPO the bottom line looks better and more readable.

[image]

Also is it not the case that the latter are far more common? Why would amsmath want writers to keep redefining the latter? The `\Re` and `\Im` are convinient but return the former.

Comment: I think they don't *keep defining* them, `amsmath` has been out there for a loooong time.

Comment: `amsmath` has nothing to do with this: `\Re` and `\Im` are defined by LaTeX in essentially the same way as in Plain TeX; apparently Knuth likes that notation. I agree with you, but that's opinion.

Comment: Try `$\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$`.

Comment: This is far from the original reason for Knuth's choice, but in many fields there would be confusion with the Reynolds Number (Re), a dimensionless velocity often typeset the same way (but without operator spacing, of course).

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234223/whats-more-common-re-im-or-fraktur-r-fraktur-i-for-real-imaginary-part

Comment: and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/vNUbloFbLwM

Comment: I know Unicode came after TeX, but U+211C ℜ is described as "real part", so the notation isn't restricted to TeX.

Comment: I do prefer the fraktur notation, it's much more elegant, and is unambiguous.

Answer (score 27):

It does not answer the question `why` but my answer shows how to get what you want to get.

### Option 1 (recommended)

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
$\!
\begin{aligned}
z &= a + b i\\
\Re(z) &= a\\
\Im{z} &= b
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 2

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
If $z=a+bi$ then\\ $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)=b$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 3

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
If $z=a+bi$ then\\ $\operatorname{\mathbb{R}e}\{z\}=a$ and $\operatorname{\mathbb{I}m}\{z\}=b$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In Option 1, `\Im{z}` allegedly produces actual braces in the output.  This isn't so; the input should be `\Im\{z\}` as in the other examples.

Answer (score 27):

`\Re` and `\Im` are defined this way in `plain.tex` by knuth:

```
\mathchardef\Re="023C
\mathchardef\Im="023D
```

this means that they are "ordinary" characters (`0`), that they are found in the
math symbol font (`2` = `cmsy`), and they are located at (hex) positions `3C` and `3D`
in that font.

the definitions were initially adopted into `amstex` along with all other names of
single symbols, and from there into `amsmath`, unchanged.

Answer (score 17):

These are the relevant lines in `fontmath.ltx`, the file that contains the basic math settings for LaTeX:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Re}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Im}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3D}
```

This is the corresponding part in `plain.tex`:

```
\font\tensy=cmsy10 % math symbols
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\fivesy=cmsy5

\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy

\mathchardef\Re="023C
\mathchardef\Im="023D
```

So the two definition point exactly to the same symbol in the same font (when the default Computer Modern fonts are used). This predates `amsmath`, because equivalent definitions were already in LaTeX 2.09 (which simply copied the math settings from Plain TeX).

The reason is simple: Knuth likes that notation.

There's no difficulty in changing it to give “Re” and “Im”, when `amsmath` is loaded:

```
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
```

Doing so has the advantage that, if a publisher prefers ℜ and ℑ, they just need to comment out the redefinition. There's nothing sacred in those symbols: one may like them or not (I don't).

Comment: unfortunately that isn't quite behaving in the same way, with Re being a symbol you can do $X_\Re$ tray that with your redefinition

Comment: @FrankMittelbach The LaTeX manual always uses `_{...}` for a reason. `;-)`

Comment: but it also says to use \"{o} ... anyway plain TeX does and in reality nobody does $x_{i}$ normally. But was just making a general comment that this kind of changes the nature of the beast. One can live with it but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach `Bitte, T\"{u}r schlie\ss en`

Comment: So you don't like the original definition of `\Re` and `\Im`? What would you propose?

Comment: @manooooh Isn’t it shown?