# Computer modern fraktur R and I

Tags: fonts, knuth

The celebrated gothic R and I glyphs are present in the Don Knuth's computer modern symbols family. Is there any "story" concerning the glyphs, e.g. why they where abandoned in the realisation of the euler "cousin", and, maybe, on which typeface Knuth took inspiration to design them? Personally, I would be very interested in discover how the whole alphabet (uppercase and lowercase) could appear, since so far I cannot figure out it nor any "font detector" helped me along this research.[image]

Comment: Without knowing anything about the true story, I might just guess that "R" and "I" were being set aside for Real and Imaginary number usage.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- It is definitely Knuth's preference to use fraktur R and I for real and imaginary numbers; other mathematicians prefer "Re" and "Im".  But the shapes that Knuth used in his Metafont fonts were not adopted into Euler because the shapes don't fit with the design of Euler.  Hermann Zapf was an exceedingly competent and noted font designer, and the design of Euler is consistent.  I don't know what Knuth's model was, but I suspect that looking at old issues of the AMS Transactions or Acta Mathematica will turn up similar shapes.

Comment: Barbara's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192692/why-does-amsmath-use-fraktur-for-real-and-imaginary-parts is perhaps related.

Comment: For many examples showing the wide range of Fraktur, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-do-i-typeset-a-fraktur-x-that-looks-like-r/320407#320407

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think the glyphs were abandoned? Knuth's Computer Modern
has no Fraktur font but Zapf's Euler has one. That is, the complete
alphabet in upper- and lowercase is available. And AMS placed the
uppercase Fraktur R and I into font eusm10 using the slots known from
cmsy10.

Knuth might have designed only these two Fraktur letters as he didn't need more. So he had a lot of freedom as there is no complete alphabet. To get Zapf's complete alphabet look at eufm10, for example.

It's impossible to say which typefaces inspired Knuth; or better, only
he might be able to say that. We know that he looked at a lot of math
books, the complete set of the Transactions of the AMS, articles by
type designers from different centuries, alphabets by artists like
Dürer, and many other sources.

When you look at the Luthersche Fraktur (1708) or the
Breitkopf-Fraktur (1750), just to name two fonts, you will find the
two-part I and elements of the decoration of the R. That is, the
letters might be influenced by old Fraktur fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I've ever written [a material](https://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/info/mathalphabets/mathalphabets.pdf) about mathematical alphabets which  contains some history, while unfortunately is in Chinese. Let me rewrite the history about the Euler Fraktur letters by Zapf here in English.

"With Donald Knuth’s assistance and encouragement, Hermann Zapf, one of the premier font designers of this century, was commissioned to create designs for Fraktur ...". (See page 3 of [User’s Guide to AMSFonts Version 2.2d](https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf)). From [a font instruction](http://www.linotype.co.jp/linotype%20volumes/Palatino%20Sans%20Brochure.pdf) (see page 23), we could find that Zapf design the Euler Fraktur letters in 1980-1983.

Zapf reshaped many letters in the `amsfonts` package which was updated in 2009 (see [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts)).